# SaveChanges() exception, complains of missing fields that are already there

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

The ActionResult below used to work but recently stopped working. `db.SaveChanges()` throws an exception complaining that `User` and `Class` fields are required. But they are already there! If I simply set `User` and `Class` to the values already there...

```
            item.User = item.User;
            item.Class = item.Class;
```

Then the exception goes away. Obviously there is something big here that I have misunderstood. If this bit of code fails, how am I supposed to update fields of a record?

Thanks for insight!!

```
    public ActionResult ApproveChange(int id)
    {
        var item = db.EnrollmentItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);

        if (item != null
            && item.State == EnrollmentState.Submitted
            && LoginUser.IsManager(ClientBusiness))
        {
            item.State = EnrollmentState.Approved;
            item.LastTouch = DateTime.UtcNow;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { State = item.State });
        }
        return Json(new { State = "error" });
    }
```

Here's the class definition

```
public class EnrollmentItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastTouch { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return 
            String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",
            User, Action, ID, State, Class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because entity framework refuses to go to the database with a model that is lacking a required property. It is null because you never fetched it from the database.
By setting them to themself you call the get method + the set method, this will trigger the lazy loading which will fetch the user and class object from the database.
To do this directly you can include these 2 properties in your firstOrDefault call like this :

```
var item = db.EnrollmentItems
               .Include(x=>x.User)
               .Include(x=>x.Class)
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
```

If you don't want to include them i guess you could also add the foreign key properties on the model so you don't have to join the tables. Your class would look this like then :

```
public class EnrollmentItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId{get;set;}
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
    public int ClassId{get;set;}
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastTouch { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return 
            String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",
            User, Action, ID, State, Class);
    }
}
```

You would have to specify the required in a mapping class but then you can update and insert on either the virtual property or the foreignkeyId(entity framework will figure it out 1 way or another).

Comment: This seems like a defect in EF… it should only check this stuff if I'm creating a new record, not updating an existing one. This operation should turn into UPDATE Table SET Field=value WHERE ID=id with no need to join tables and retrieve more rows. The referential integrity built into the database insures that the existing User and Class fields are valid. EF is doing a poor job of insulating me from the implementation AND forcing extra work. OK rant off.

Finally, where should I have learned about this? Assuming there is other EF trickery afoot, is there something I should read?

Comment: Would it be correct to say the reason it appeared these fields were already there is because the debugger called `item.ToString()` which retrieved them? Actually, it must have called ToString() on a copy of the item because `db.SaveChanges()` still threw an exception when I stepped through.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, was away for a few. If you debug or call ToString your lazy loading will fetch it for you. Not sure if he clones the object or if it's actually loaded. And about your rant : you specified these properties as required but in your unitofwork(context) you have not loaded them into memory. EF can't depend solely upon the referential integrity because your context and the database scheme might be different. As for reading material i'm not that big of a reader but i suspect the required attribute on relationships isn't that much used(at least i don't).